# Creating mock with Mockito for class that extends generic class

Tags: java, android, generics, testing, mockito

Hi guys I'm having trouble creating a mock.
Here is the code:

The class that I am trying to mock:

```
public class MyClass extends BaseClass<ClassView>{
    //code goes here
}
```

On the test:

```
MyClass mockMyClass;

@Test
public void setUp(){
    mockMyClass = mock(MyClass.class);
}
```

Also tried:

```
@Mock MyClass mockMyClass;

@Test
public void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
}
```

The error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
Mockito cannot mock this class: class com.packageName.MyClass

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.
```

I'm thinking there is an issue when creating a mock for a class that extends a class with generic parameters.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you show the annotations your your test class?

Comment: Can you include any actual errors you're getting in your question?

Comment: @JamesMcCracken updated the question with the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot two mandatory annotations of your TestClass:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MyClass.class})
public class FirstTest {
    MyClass mockMyClass;

    @Test
    public void setUp(){
        mockMyClass = mock(MyClass.class);
    }
}
```

Your test needs to be executed with the `PowerMockRunner` and you also need to prepare for test all classes you want to mock. If you keep that in mind it will work fine :)